# Sorting and Filter Over PII Data

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch, redis

I have a large set of *User PII* data, currently, we are storing on Relational Data encrypted with *AWS KMS*. Now I have to paginate data based on `UserName`. The only we have to do right now is load all decrypted data on memory or cache and then do the sorting and pagination.

Please suggest any approach, Tool, or framework which supports sorting on *PII* masked data. Services are using Java as language.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is being updated rarely then as an option - you can use the calculated order(rank function, user_name_order column) and order by that column instead of PII data.

you can create a cron job to update the rank or come up with some event for rank updating.
example of event: onCreate/onUpdate a userName - recalculate all ranks(decrypt data, update user_name_order columns), etc..